# Permission denied in /data

Tags: cyanogenmod, internal-storage, file-permissions

My phone is getting out of storage space warnings and most of this is due to log files in /data that I cannot get to.

I'm using [CyanogenMod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJrN.png) and use Terminal to gain shell access.  Issue su in the root filesystem,  `cd data`, then `ls`.   That's when I get permission denied.

[image]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

What do I need to do to gain permission to clear out these large, inaccessible log files?

Comment: If you'll add as an answer I'll green check you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not even operating as root - the symbol before each command is still `$` instead of `#`. Double check the root-related options in Developer options - allow root for shell.